# How can I cut info in a file from A to B?

Tags: javascript, excel, batch-file, cmd, vbscript

### I had just learned about how to use the `for` command in Command Prompt, now I would like to learn this:

---

In `file0.txt`:

```
start:file
 tag1:a1
 tag2:a2
 tag3:a3
end:file
start:file
 tag1:b1
 tag2:b2
 tag3:b3
end:file
```

---

How can I cut/copy from the line [start] to the line [end] to another file (i.e. write it into another file like file1.txt) in Command Prompt?

*if you don't get it, here's what I would like:

turn the text from `file0.txt` to this ⇩

---

`file1.txt`:

```
start:file
tag1:a1
tag2:a2
tag3:a3
end:file
```

`file2.txt`

```
start:file
tag1:b1
tag2:b2
tag3:b3
end:file
```

---

(Actually, can this be done in Command Prompt? If not, are there any language supporting this?)

Comment: to literally answer your question: yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy - do it like you would do it by hand (every time, a line starts with "start:", start a new file):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set n=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file0.txt) do (
  echo %%a|findstr /bi "start:" >nul && set /a n+=1
  echo %%a>>"file!n!.txt"
)
```

Same logic will work in every language.